# How does a logic level converter with a N-channel MOSFET work?

Tags: mosfet, level-shifting, logic-level

I am trying to convert a 3.3 V digital signal to a 5 V digital signal. One way to do this is to use a logic level converter with a N-channel MOSFET and 2 resistors. I found the following schematic:

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://www.digikey.com/en/blog/logic-level-shifting-basics)</sup>

The source of the image gives an explanation of the circuit, but it is not entirely clear to me. They also don't explain what the value of the resistors should be. Could someone give me 'dumbed-down' explanation of the circuit and explain what value resistors I should use?

Comment: Which part of that explanation do you not understand? Are there any words or concepts you do not know?

Comment: Does [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/555631/understanding-how-this-bi-directional-logic-level-shift-works) answer your question?

Comment: [This](http://www.penguintutor.com/electronics/mosfet-levelshift) (the paragraph 'Bi-directional logic level shifter') also explains it quite well.

Comment: @Velvel Yes! These explanations help. They use 10kOhm resistors for their examples, but they don't explain why. What influence does the value have on the circuit?

Comment: Those resistors simply act as pull-up resistors. When the MOSFET is open, both sides will be pulled-up to their respective supply voltages (in case they're not actively driven to a HIGH voltage).

Comment: This is a duplicate. I just explained the exact same thing within a week or two, and likely it was a duplicate too. I will vote to close when I find the previous question. Also the resistance values will depend on what you need and we can't know what you will do with this circuit.

Comment: See also [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/367055/53368) one for some diagrams of operation.